# Compiling Rails / ReactJS not working in production (heroku), but working locally. CSSSyntaxError : MissedSemicolon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, webpack, webpacker

For the note I already pushed my Rails / ReactJS app several times withtout any troubles on Heroku.

After some changes i'm trying to re-push it, but I get the following error =>

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. heroku/nodejs
       2. heroku/ruby
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       USE_YARN_CACHE=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.16.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.11
       Resolving yarn version 1.22.x...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.10)
       Installed yarn 1.22.10
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.22.10
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.12.10" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.12.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development@7.12.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning " > @bumaga/tabs@0.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".
       warning " > @bumaga/tabs@0.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0".
       warning " > react-stripe-elements@6.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0".
       warning " > react-stripe-elements@6.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0".
       warning " > redux-form@8.3.7" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.4.2".
       warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
       warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 54.06s.
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       yarn install v1.22.10
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.12.10" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.12.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development@7.12.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning " > @bumaga/tabs@0.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".
       warning " > @bumaga/tabs@0.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0".
       warning " > react-stripe-elements@6.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0".
       warning " > react-stripe-elements@6.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0".
       warning " > redux-form@8.3.7" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.4.2".
       warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
       warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
       Done in 10.51s.
       
-----> Caching build
       - yarn cache
       
-----> Build succeeded!
 !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type
 !     Unmet dependencies don't fail yarn install but may cause runtime issues
       https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.2.11
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
###### WARNING:
       Your app was upgraded to bundler 2.2.11.
       Previously you had a successful deploy with bundler 2.1.4.
       
       If you see problems related to the bundler version please refer to:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues
       
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.0
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.11
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       Your Gemfile lists the gem dotenv-rails (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-gem.git
       Using rake 13.0.3
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
       Using minitest 5.14.3
       Using thread_safe 0.3.6
       Using builder 3.2.4
       Using erubi 1.10.0
       Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
       Using crass 1.0.6
       Using rack 2.2.3
       Using nio4r 2.5.4
       Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Using mini_mime 1.0.2
       Using jsonapi-renderer 0.2.2
       Using arel 9.0.0
       Using mimemagic 0.3.5
       Using public_suffix 4.0.6
       Using execjs 2.7.0
       Using base32 0.3.4
       Using bcrypt 3.1.16
       Using msgpack 1.3.3
       Using bundler 2.2.11
       Using mini_magick 4.11.0
       Using ffi 1.14.2
       Using multi_json 1.15.0
       Using carrierwave_backgrounder 0.0.2
       Using excon 0.78.1
       Using formatador 0.2.5
       Using mime-types-data 3.2020.1104
       Using ipaddress 0.8.3
       Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Using method_source 1.0.0
       Using thor 1.0.1
       Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Fetching unf_ext 0.0.7.7
       Fetching dotenv 2.7.6
       Using foreman 0.87.2
       Using multi_xml 0.6.0
       Using jwt 2.2.2
       Using rotp 6.2.0
       Using useragent 0.16.10
       Using hashie 3.6.0
       Fetching http-accept 1.7.0
       Fetching netrc 0.11.0
       Installing dotenv 2.7.6
       Installing netrc 0.11.0
       Installing http-accept 1.7.0
       Using pg 1.2.3
       Using puma 3.12.6
       Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
       Using redis 4.2.5
       Using tilt 2.0.10
       Using semantic_range 2.3.1
       Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.7 with native extensions
       Fetching stripe 5.30.0
       Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Using i18n 1.8.7
       Using nokogiri 1.10.10
       Using rack-test 1.1.0
       Using websocket-driver 0.7.3
       Using mail 2.7.1
       Using marcel 0.3.3
       Using addressable 2.7.0
       Using autoprefixer-rails 10.2.0.0
       Using bootsnap 1.5.1
       Using warden 1.2.9
       Using sprockets 3.7.2
       Using rack-cors 1.1.1
       Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
       Installing stripe 5.30.0
       Using uglifier 4.2.0
       Using tzinfo 1.2.9
       Using ruby-vips 2.0.17
       Using streamio-ffmpeg 2.0.0
       Using mime-types 3.3.1
       Using coffee-script 2.4.1
       Using sassc 2.4.0
       Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
       Using figaro 1.2.0
       Using omniauth 1.9.0
       Using loofah 2.8.0
       Using turbolinks 5.2.1
       Using activesupport 5.2.4.4
       Using image_processing 1.12.1
       Using fog-core 2.2.3
       Using httparty 0.18.1
       Using font-awesome-sass 5.15.1
       Using sass-listen 4.0.0
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
       Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Using globalid 0.4.2
       Using activemodel 5.2.4.4
       Using case_transform 0.2
       Using groupdate 2.5.2
       Using jsonapi-serializers 1.0.1
       Using jbuilder 2.10.1
       Using fog-json 1.2.0
       Using fog-xml 0.1.3
       Using actionview 5.2.4.4
       Using activejob 5.2.4.4
       Using activerecord 5.2.4.4
       Using carrierwave 2.1.0
       Using sass 3.7.4
       Using actionpack 5.2.4.4
       Using arel-helpers 2.12.0
       Using carrierwave-video 0.6.0
       Using carrierwave-video-thumbnailer 0.1.4
       Using fog-aws 3.7.0
       Using friendly_id 5.4.2
       Using actioncable 5.2.4.4
       Using actionmailer 5.2.4.4
       Using active_model_serializers 0.10.10
       Using activestorage 5.2.4.4
       Using railties 5.2.4.4
       Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Using carrierwave_direct 2.1.0
       Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Using responders 3.0.1
       Using rails 5.2.4.4
       Fetching dotenv-rails 2.7.6
       Using sass-rails 5.1.0
       Using webpacker 5.2.1
       Using forest_liana 5.4.0
       Using devise 4.7.3
       Fetching devise_token_auth 1.1.5
       Installing dotenv-rails 2.7.6
       Installing devise_token_auth 1.1.5
       Fetching unf 0.1.4
       Installing unf 0.1.4
       Fetching domain_name 0.5.20190701
       Installing domain_name 0.5.20190701
       Fetching http-cookie 1.0.3
       Installing http-cookie 1.0.3
       Fetching rest-client 2.1.0
       Installing rest-client 2.1.0
       Using mailjet 1.6.0 from https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-gem.git (at master@675f75f)
       Bundle complete! 48 Gemfile dependencies, 124 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Removing bundler (2.1.4)
       Removing devise_token_auth (1.1.3)
       Removing simple_form (5.0.3)
       Bundle completed (9.33s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       /tmp/build_e1471a4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.4/lib/active_record/type.rb:27: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
       /tmp/build_e1471a4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.4/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:9: warning: The called method `add_modifier' is defined here
       /tmp/build_e1471a4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
       /tmp/build_e1471a4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:111: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
       /tmp/build_e1471a4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.4.4/lib/active_model/type/integer.rb:13: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
       /tmp/build_e1471a4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.4.4/lib/active_model/type/value.rb:8: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
       /tmp/build_e1471a4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/specialized_string.rb:12: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
       /tmp/build_e1471a4f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.4.4/lib/active_model/type/value.rb:8: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
       yarn install v1.22.10
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.12.10" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.12.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development@7.12.12" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning " > @bumaga/tabs@0.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".
       warning " > @bumaga/tabs@0.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0".
       warning " > react-stripe-elements@6.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0".
       warning " > react-stripe-elements@6.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.5.4 || ^16.0.0-0".
       warning " > redux-form@8.3.7" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.4.2".
       warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
       warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 51.78s.
       I, [2021-03-17T11:29:21.549633 #3503]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_e1471a4f/public/assets/adhesion-b7f06c2d9ff4f288a034bc9110a5e730795b0207b75984d4483e6219b43bb0d1.svg
       I, [2021-03-17T11:29:21.550575 #3503]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_e1471a4f/public/assets/adhesion-b7f06c2d9ff4f288a034bc9110a5e730795b0207b75984d4483e6219b43bb0d1.svg.gz
       I, [2021-03-17T11:29:24.153962 #3503]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_e1471a4f/public/assets/README-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.md
       I, [2021-03-17T11:29:30.200009 #3503]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_e1471a4f/public/assets/application-7a44779857db323d1bc9ccf63db9914a5ce8ff8d23f6f9beb9853fb60ff66e8c.css
       I, [2021-03-17T11:29:30.200642 #3503]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_e1471a4f/public/assets/application-7a44779857db323d1bc9ccf63db9914a5ce8ff8d23f6f9beb9853fb60ff66e8c.css.gz
       Compiling...
       Compilation failed:
       CssSyntaxError: /tmp/build_e1471a4f/css/Routes-f5978686.css:900:4437: Missed semicolon
           at Input.error (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:128:16)
           at Parser.checkMissedSemicolon (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:601:22)
           at Parser.decl (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:284:46)
           at Parser.other (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:164:12)
           at Parser.parse (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:75:16)
           at parse (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/parse.js:17:12)
           at new LazyResult (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:64:16)
           at Processor.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:142:12)
           at Processor.process (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:121:23)
           at Function.creator.process (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:148:43)
           at OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin.processCss (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:73:21)
           at Object.processor (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:13:18)
           at /tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:150:10
           at arrayEach (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/lodash/_arrayEach.js:15:9)
           at forEach (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/lodash/forEach.js:38:10)
           at OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin.process (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:147:5)
           at /tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:178:28
           at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:22:17)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
           at /tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1409:36
           at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
           at /tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1405:32
           at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
           at Compilation.seal (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1342:27)
           at /tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:675:18
           at /tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1261:4
           at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
           at Compilation.finish (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1253:28)
           at /tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:672:17
           at _done (eval at create (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
           at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:620:22)
           at /tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1185:12
           at /tmp/build_e1471a4f/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1097:9
       
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

I tried many things as :

- Delete some recent packages
- Check every line of code and update ever JS and SCSS files with missing semicolons
- Delete heroku buildpacks and re-add them.
- Create a new heroku app

All of these attempts give me the same error.

I don't really know where to search anymore.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Joe

Here are some files that may help you feel free to ask me more outputs or files.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@bumaga/tabs": "^0.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "final-form": "^4.20.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "j-toker": "^0.0.10-beta3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-deparam": "^0.5.3",
    "jquery.cookie": "^1.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.70",
    "polyfill": "^0.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "pubsub-js": "^1.9.2",
    "query-string": "^6.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.1",
    "react-final-form": "^6.5.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.12.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-share": "^4.3.1",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.7",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: In production the assets are precompiled with RAILS_ENV=production. Run this on your local see if it passes: `NODE_ENV=production ./bin/webpack`

Comment: Or set `compile: true` in `webpacker.yml` for `development`. The error is raised at precompilation step

Comment: Thank you for your response. Il ran `NODE_ENV=production ./bin/webpack` it passes without any troubles. 
For you second comment, since the beginning `compile` is on `true` for `development`

Comment: Create a new heroku app and deploy without that css that fails. Narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide more log information what went wrong by going here:
[image]

The information is relevant because it says which npm and node version it is using. Compare it to your local node and npm version. It might also say when it fails to install some packages. The shown error would then be a consecutive error.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  }
```

You listed `webpack-dev-server` as a develop dependency. Are you sure it is not needed in deployment/production?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
I'm sorry maybe it wasn't clear, this is already the heroku logs errors. I have updated it with the full build logs. 

I added the `webpack-dev-server` to the production my bad.

Comment: The updated logs show you are having trouble installing the dependencies. Ensure your code is working on Linux general before proceeding to host it on Heroku.

Comment: Eveyrthing is working fine locally on my mac. I don't really know how to ensure that my code is working on Linux, I've never had this kind of problem before, I'll try to dig in ...